# Exporting javascript arrays into XLS with Alasql

Tags: javascript, excel, alasql

I had the task to import excel files in javascript and decided to use AlaSQL. It worked as expected.

Now i need to export excel as well and it gets more complicated.
I have several arrays that I would like to place separatly. 
Is it possible to do so ?
If so, how can I ask for a specific location for my array?

I tried exporting with :

```
alasql("SELECT * INTO XLSX('grilles.xlsx',{headers:true}) FROM ? ",[data]);
```

where data can be a single array or a concat, but only the one type of columns apply.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual question? Please read the [help]. This question is very vague, lacks information on what you've tried and is likely too broad